# How to normalize the data

Tags: data-mining

Normalize the data set to make the norm of each data point equal to 1.

x1 (1.5,1.7) [x1 (i,j)]

x2 (2,1.9)

x3 (1.6,1.8)

x4 (1.2,1.5)

x5 (1.5,1.0)

Given a new data point, x = (1.4; 1.6) as a query,

The solution after normalization

x(0.6585,0.7526)
x1(0.6616,0.7498 )
x2(0.7250,0.6887)
x3(0.6644,0.7474)
x4(0.6247,0.7809)
x5(0.8321,0.5547)

But iam confused how the solution is obtained, i tried with different formula's none of them worked.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: using    Xi,norm = (Xi - Xmean)/(Xsd) & Xi,norm = (Xi - Xmin)/(Xmax-Xmin)

Comment: Recall the definition of *norm of each data point*.

Answer (score 6):

x(1.4,1.6) . norm(x)= sqrt( (1.4)^2 +(1.6)^2) ~ 2.13.

Normalized x is(1.4 /2.13 , 1.6/2.13)

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

You have been trying column wise normalization.
But the text demands a normalization *to unit length*.